# What happens if a non-suspend function is called from a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

One of the key concepts of coroutines in Kotlin is that a **suspend function must be called from a coroutine or another suspend function**.

However, a suspend function can call any kind of function, suspend or normal.
What is the consequence of that? (This is not a real scenario i have, just want to know for theoretical reasons)

I imagine that in that scenario the only point of creating a coroutine would be to change the context (thread) before calling it, so it doesn´t block the main thread.
However, would all the other advantages of coroutines be lost? (cooperative cancellation, structured concurrency...)

Comment: nothing, literally nothing. except when you have to call `withContext` because of the non suspending method has relations to the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a suspending function calls another suspending function, then the coroutine is suspended, until the result is returned.

Calling a regular function from a suspending function will block the thread. Which thread? Well, that depends on the Dispatcher you're using. `IO` is able to spawn hundred of threads. But the `Default` dispatcher has same amount of threads as your CPUs count. Meaning that while this won't block other coroutines, it will reduce the amount of available resources.

Meaning: don't invoke non-suspending function that may block for a long period of time on this dispatcher, same as you don't block your `UI` thread.

And yes, suspending function may produce the same results, if you're do something like a busy loop without `yield()` or any other suspend invocation in it.

Comment: The point you want to make with your first sentence is lost if you take it literally. Calling a suspendable function doesn't suspend the coroutine; only calling `suspendCoroutine` and its siblings does that. Also, if enough concurrent coroutines call blocking code on `Default` it _will_ block all coroutine progress.

Comment: You're right. It may be more accurate to say that invocation may or may not suspend the invoking coroutine. But I think this kind of accuracy will confuse the readers more than it will help them.

Answer (score 3):

Suspend functions can be suspended in between and resumed later. Calling a normal function from a suspend function you lose the ability to pause the execution.

when a suspend function is compiled, kotlin compiler adds a continuation object as a parameter in the arguments. This continuation object is required for suspending a coroutine. When a suspend function calls another suspend function it passes the continuation object same is true with co-routines.

if a non-suspend function is called from suspend function you just wont be able to use co-routines from that function... that's it

Comment: > Calling a normal function from a suspend function you lose the ability
> to pause the execution.

Disagree, you won't loose ability to pause. Root suspend function will work as you expect

Comment: I think he just meant what others has stated in this thread: that the non-suspend function can't be paused.

Answer (score 1):

> However, would all the other advantages of coroutines be lost? (cooperative cancellation, structured concurrency...)

Even a non-suspendable function can participate in cooperative cancellation by explicitly checking the `CoroutineContext.isActive` flag. This is more of a theoretical fact, though.

If a function performs a blocking IO operation, it will not respond to cancellation requests. The operation will have to complete on its own.

As for structured concurrency, almost the opposite of your concern is true: it is a Kotlin best practice to launch child coroutines from a *non-suspendable* function that is instead an extension on `CoroutineScope` and calls the coroutine builders with it as the receiver.

Comment: Let's say I have root suspend function, launched by ViewModelScope. And inside it I call non-suspend function which does some heavy work, for example Sqlite query using Room. Then at the 50% of that query I cancel that job. What the result I get, leaking? Room won't stop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best to try it out and make sure. If the blocking code is non-interruptible, there's nothing you can do to stop it from the outside, and interruption itself is a dangerous mechanism because you never know what will throw `InterruptedException`. If you did the Kotlin side right, the coroutine would not complete until the blocking operation completes.

Comment: okay, I'll try. I ask it because if there weren't any differences, there weren't be any necessary at adding support of suspend to Room's DAO and Retrofit2's Services

Comment: @AkbolatSSS When you cancel a job it will continue to run and coroutine moves to Cancelling state. The job is canceled fully only when the work inside it is completed

Comment: Adding to @FarazAhmed's statement, the coroutine will get the `CancellationException` as soon as it attempts to suspend itself, and the code is required to let it through without catching, so that it escapes the coroutine's top level. This is not only trivially easy to break, it is actually considered a best practice to have that `catch (e: Exception)` at the top level so you take control of your exceptions. That code must be made coroutine-aware and be transparent to `CancellationException`.