# Do suspend functions suspend coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, suspend

I am confused actually. for example, I know suspendCoroutine function which is a suspend function that suspends a coroutine. but do all suspend functions suspend coroutines? in addition I know when a coroutine is suspended it remove from the corresponding thread for a while and other coroutines or tasks can resume and run on this thread.

***I want to reach the conclusion that if all suspend functions do not suspend the coroutine, so what is the difference between put suspend function in the coroutine or a non-suspend function in the coroutine?***

Comment: This might help out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502536/what-happens-if-a-non-suspend-function-is-called-from-a-coroutine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Marking a function `suspend` gives it the *capability* to suspend the coroutine, but it will only actually suspend the coroutine if it internally calls another suspend function that suspends the coroutine. The suspend functions that *directly* suspend a coroutine are in the standard library. Among these are `suspendCoroutine()` and `suspendCancellableCoroutine()`. You will not often use these. They are most commonly used to convert non-coroutine APIs into suspend functions.

Some of the commonly used functions that *indirectly* suspend a coroutine are `withContext()`, `delay()`, `Job.join()` and `Deferred.await()`.